# Quartz Job unable to use Spring JpaRepository functions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, quartz

> Job1 Performing
>       at org.eko.BusinessJobs.Job1.doPerform(Job1.java:23)
>       at org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobA.executeInternal(BusinessJobA.java:34)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
>       at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
>       at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
>   [Thu Jun 22 14:07:07 IST 2017] Hello from Quartz! null

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.eko">
  <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
 </context:component-scan>
 
 <jpa:repositories base-package="org.eko.repository" />
 
 <task:annotation-driven/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
  id="entityManagerFactory">
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.eko.entity" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="jpaProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="persistenceProvider">
   <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
  </property>
 </bean> 
 
  <!-- 
 
  <bean id="dataSource" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Simpli_bank_Scheduler"/>
      <property name = "username" value = "root"/>
      <property name = "password" value = "1234"/>
   </bean>
   
  -->
  
   <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <!-- Connection properties -->
     <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
     <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Simpli_bank_Scheduler" />
     <property name="user" value="root" />
     <property name="password" value="1234" />
     
     <!-- Pool properties -->
     <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
     <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
     <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
     <property name="maxStatements" value="500" />
     <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
     <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
  </bean>  
   
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
<!--  
 <bean id="Job1" class="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobA">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"> </property>
 </bean>
 
 <bean name="BusinessJobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass">
            <bean factory-bean="Job1" factory-method="setJob1"></bean>
        </property>
 </bean>
 
  <bean id="BusinessJobA" class="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobA" />

  <bean id="quartzJobFactory" class="org.eko.configuration.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory">
     <property name="ignoredUnknownProperties" value="applicationContext"/>
 </bean>    

 <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
     <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
     <property name="jobFactory" ref="quartzJobFactory"/>
  <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/> 
    
     <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
     <property name="schedulerName" value="quartzScheduler"/>
     <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
     <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false"/>
     <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
     <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">50</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="BusinessObjectA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobA"/>
</bean>

<bean id="BusinessObjectB" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="BusinessObjectC" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobC"/>
</bean>

<bean id="BusinessObjectD" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobD"/>
</bean>
-->
<!-- 
<bean name="businessJobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobA"/>
    <property name="group" value="Group1"/>
</bean>

<task:annotation-driven/> 

<bean id="businessJobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">  
   <property name="jobClass" value="org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobA"/>  
   <property name="jobDataAsMap">  
     <map>  
       <entry key="name" value="Job1"/>  
     </map>  
   </property>  
   <property name="durability" value="true"/>  
 </bean> 

 <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">  
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="businessJobA" />  
   <property name="cronExpression" value="0/2 * * * * ?"/>  
 </bean> 
 
 <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">  
  <property name="jobDetails">  
    <list>  
      <ref bean="businessJobA" />  
    </list>  
  </property>  
  <property name="triggers">  
    <list>  
      <ref bean="cronTrigger" />  
    </list>  
  </property>  
 </bean> -->
 
 <bean id="job1" class="org.eko.BusinessJobs.Job1"/>
 <bean id="job2" class="org.eko.BusinessJobs.Job2"/>
 <bean id="job3" class="org.eko.BusinessJobs.Job3"/>
 <bean id="job4" class="org.eko.BusinessJobs.Job4"/>
 
 <bean id="job1job" class = "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">  
  <property name="targetObject" ref="job1"/>  
  <property name="targetMethod" value="doPerform"/>  
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="job2job" class = "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">  
  <property name="targetObject" ref="job2"/>  
  <property name="targetMethod" value="doPerform"/>  
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="job3job" class = "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">  
  <property name="targetObject" ref="job3"/>  
  <property name="targetMethod" value="doPerform"/>  
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="job4job" class = "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">  
  <property name="targetObject" ref="job4"/>  
  <property name="targetMethod" value="doPerform"/>  
 </bean>

 <bean id="simpleTrigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">  
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="job1job" />  
   <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />  
   <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
   <property name="repeatCount" value="5" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="simpleTrigger2" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">  
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="job2job" />  
   <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />  
   <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
   <property name="repeatCount" value="5" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="simpleTrigger3" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">  
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="job3job" />  
   <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />  
   <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
   <property name="repeatCount" value="5" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="simpleTrigger4" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">  
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="job4job" />  
   <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />  
   <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
   <property name="repeatCount" value="5" />
 </bean>  
 
 <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">  
  <property name="jobDetails">  
    <list>  
      <ref bean="job1job" />
      <ref bean="job2job" />
      <ref bean="job3job" />
      <ref bean="job4job" />  
    </list>  
  </property>  
  <property name="triggers">  
    <list>  
      <ref bean="simpleTrigger1" />
      <ref bean="simpleTrigger2" />
      <ref bean="simpleTrigger3" />
      <ref bean="simpleTrigger4" />  
    </list>  
  </property>  
 </bean>
</beans>
```

```html
package org.eko.jobs;

import java.util.Date;

import org.eko.BusinessJobs.Job1;
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;


@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class BusinessJobA extends QuartzJobBean
{
 public static int REPEATINTERVALINMILLISECONDS=2000;
 public static int REPEATCOUNT=20;
 
 Job1 job1=new Job1();

 @Override
 protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
  
  SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
  
  String name = arg0.getMergedJobDataMap().getString("name");
        System.out.println("[" + new Date() + "] Hello from Quartz! " + name);
  
  System.out.println("Executing Business Object A");
  try
  {
   job1.doPerform();
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

```html
package org.eko.BusinessJobs;

import java.util.List;

import org.eko.entity.SimpliJob;
import org.eko.repository.SimpliJobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Job1 {

 @Autowired
 private SimpliJobRepository simpliJobRepository;
 
 public void doPerform()
 {
  System.out.println("\nJob1 Performing");
  
  Sort sortID=new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC,"id"));
  
  List<SimpliJob> jobsDescID=simpliJobRepository.findAll(sortID);
  for (SimpliJob simpliJob : jobsDescID) {
   System.out.println(simpliJob);
  }
  System.out.println("\nJob1 Done\n");
 }
}
```

```js
package org.eko.controller;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.eko.entity.SimpliJob;
import org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobA;
import org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobB;
import org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobC;
import org.eko.jobs.BusinessJobD;
import org.eko.repository.SimpliJobRepository;
import org.eko.service.InitDbService;
import org.quartz.DateBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class QuartzSchedulerController {
 
 JobDetail jobDetail1;
 JobDetail jobDetail2;
 JobDetail jobDetail3;
 JobDetail jobDetail4;
 Trigger trigger1;
 Trigger trigger2;
 Trigger trigger3;
 Trigger trigger4;
 Scheduler scheduler;
 
 @Autowired
 private SimpliJobRepository simpliJobRepository;
 
 public void scheduleJob(SimpliJob simpliJob) throws SchedulerException
 {
  scheduler=new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
  if(simpliJob.getStatus()==1){
  if(simpliJob.getId()==1)
  {
   jobDetail1=JobBuilder.newJob(BusinessJobA.class).withIdentity(simpliJob.getName(),simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).build();
   trigger1=(Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("Trigger1",simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).startAt(DateBuilder.dateOf(simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.SECOND), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.YEAR))).withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(BusinessJobA.REPEATINTERVALINMILLISECONDS).withRepeatCount(BusinessJobA.REPEATCOUNT)).forJob(jobDetail1).build();
   scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail1,trigger1);
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectA Scheduled!");
  }
  if(simpliJob.getId()==2)
  {
   jobDetail2=JobBuilder.newJob(BusinessJobB.class).withIdentity(simpliJob.getName(),simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).build();
   trigger2=(Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("Trigger2",simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).startAt(DateBuilder.dateOf(simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.SECOND), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.YEAR))).withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(BusinessJobB.REPEATINTERVALINMILLISECONDS).withRepeatCount(BusinessJobB.REPEATCOUNT)).forJob(jobDetail2).build();
   scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail2,trigger2);
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectB Scheduled!");
  }
  if(simpliJob.getId()==3)
  {
   jobDetail3=JobBuilder.newJob(BusinessJobC.class).withIdentity(simpliJob.getName(),simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).build();
   trigger3=(Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("Trigger3",simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).startAt(DateBuilder.dateOf(simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.SECOND), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.YEAR))).withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(BusinessJobC.REPEATINTERVALINMILLISECONDS).withRepeatCount(BusinessJobC.REPEATCOUNT)).forJob(jobDetail3).build();
   scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail3,trigger3);
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectC Scheduled!");
  }
  if(simpliJob.getId()==4)
  {
   jobDetail4=JobBuilder.newJob(BusinessJobD.class).withIdentity(simpliJob.getName(),simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).build();
   trigger4=(Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("Trigger4",simpliJob.getSimpliGroup()).startAt(DateBuilder.dateOf(simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.SECOND), simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,simpliJob.getStartTime().get(Calendar.YEAR))).withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(BusinessJobD.REPEATINTERVALINMILLISECONDS).withRepeatCount(BusinessJobD.REPEATCOUNT)).forJob(jobDetail4).build();
   scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail4,trigger4);
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectD Scheduled!");
  }
  simpliJob.setStatus(2);
  simpliJobRepository.save(simpliJob);
  }
  else
  {
   System.err.println("Job Already Scheduled!");
  }
  scheduler.start();
 }
 
 public void unscheduleJob(SimpliJob simpliJob) throws SchedulerException
 {
  if(simpliJob.getStatus()==2){
  if(simpliJob.getId()==1)
  {
   scheduler.unscheduleJob(trigger1.getKey());
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectA descheduled!");
  }
  if(simpliJob.getId()==2)
  {
   scheduler.unscheduleJob(trigger2.getKey());
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectB descheduled!");
  }
  if(simpliJob.getId()==3)
  {
   scheduler.unscheduleJob(trigger3.getKey());
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectC descheduled!");
  }
  if(simpliJob.getId()==4)
  {
   scheduler.unscheduleJob(trigger4.getKey());
   System.out.println("BusinessObjectD descheduled!");
  }
  simpliJob.setStatus(1);
  simpliJobRepository.save(simpliJob);
  }
  else
  {
   System.err.println("Job Not Scheduled!");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your job bean manually instead of injecting it. Here is how you should do this:

```
@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class BusinessJobA extends QuartzJobBean
{

    @Autowired
    private Job1 job1;

    /* ... */

}
```

Also you're not setting any job data when you create it, try using something like this:

```
JobBuilder
    .newJob(BusinessJobD.class)
    .withIdentity(simpliJob.getName(),simpliJob.getSimpliGroup())
    .usingJobData("name", "some name")
    .build();
```